# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object in C# console application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to write simple program for console application, but I am facing this error every time.
  few months ago this exact code was running fine, but now it is giving me this error,
  I reinstalled my visual studio and oracle database, but then also the same error...
  Please Help...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;

namespace dataTestDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string constr;
            constr = "User Id = hr; Password = tiger; data source = localhost: 1521/ORCL; pooling = false";
            try
            {
                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = constr;
                con.open();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select salary from employees where employee_id = 109";

                OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())// Here, I am getting this error..
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Employee Salary = " + reader.GetString(0));
                }

                con.close();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Data);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEQGp.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are setting your connection on the command object, and you also should open the connection.

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = constr;

// Open the connection
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

// Set the connection on the command object
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "select salary from employees where employee_id = 109";
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// Don't forget to close your connection at some point
```

I purposely left out error checking and assuring the connection is closed after you use it. There is an example at the bottom of the following link that should help you out further.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you create a an object called *con* which is of type *OracleConnection*. But after setting the *ConnectionString* property, you never use this object. My guess is that you need to open the connection and somehow link the *cmd* object to this connection.